# How can I operate on each element of an array and also collect or store those elements?

Tags: arrays, ruby, each

I’m trying to build a method that squares each element of an array and returns a new array of those squared numbers. Can’t use any methods other than `each` (e.g. no `map` or `collect`). I tried setting a new array:

```
def square_array(array)
  array.each do |element|
  new_array = element ** 2
 end 
end
```

but it returns the original values. Help?

Comment: It is impossible to do it only using `each`. Why can't you use any other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the elements on a new array and return it, you're just creating a variable new_array over and over with the square of the current element.

```
def square_array(array)
    new_array = []
    array.each do |element|
        new_array << element ** 2
    end
    new_array
end

# shorter

def square_array(array)
    new_array = []
    array.each { |e| new_array << e ** 2 }
    new_array
end

# even shorter

def square_array(array)
    Array.new(array.size) { |i| array[i] ** 2}
end
```

Comment: The solutions here use either the method `<<` or `new` (besides `**`).

Comment: @sawa I guess one can discount them as they are not invoked on `array` variable :-/ though the third version `# even shorter` uses the `Array#size` method and may not be valid if we take the question literally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to do this:

```
[].tap {|result| array.each {|i| result << i ** 2}}
```